# categorize arrays AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got this array :

```
var usersArray:Array = new Array("this is array1 and it's a good array","this is array2", "this is array3", "this is array4", "this is array");
usersArray.push(usersArray.splice(usersArray.indexOf("UserID"), 1));

var companion:String = usersArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (usersArray.length - 1))];

  trace(companion);
```

Is it possible to class the array with letter or number as my array could be very long ?

Like

```
if (companion==A){
trace("this is array 1")
}
```

Instead of

```
if (companion=="this is array1 and it's a good array"){
trace("this is array 1")
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: `usersArray.indexOf("UserID")` is -1, what are you splicing at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question well,you can set variable for strings in your array:

```
var usersArray:Array = new Array("this is array1 and it's a good array","this is array2", "this is array3", "this is array4", "this is array");
usersArray.push(usersArray.splice(usersArray.indexOf("UserID"), 1));
var A:String=userArray[0];
var B:String=userArray[1];
var C:String=userArray[2];
var D:String=userArray[3];
var E:String=userArray[4];



var companion:String = usersArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (usersArray.length - 1))];

  trace(companion);   

if (companion==A){
  trace("this is array 1")
}
```

or you can simply write:

```
 if(companion==userArray[0]){
  trace("this is array 1")
}
```